# I want to control the stack and what happens when the user presses the back button on the Android system, not my app

Tags: android, stack, back-button

I want to know if I can control the action my application takes when a user presses the back button on the android device instead of using the application's navigation that I created. Is there a way of creating an intent when the back button is pressed and also, is there a way to limit how many Activities from my app are in the stack (could I tell the android device to only remember the last 3 Activities from my app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to override onBackPressed in your activity and then you can do what you want. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

There are also lots of answers here on stack overflow regarding manipulating the back stack (the stack of activities that are navigated through as one presses the back button.) I could post links to some random ones that I found, but you are probably best to search yourself. Read the docs and search for the android *back stack*.

Comment: ok, thank you. I have heard it's unwise to terminate an app yourself and you should just let the OS do it. But sometimes it seems stupid to let the user go back through the stack. Would you suggest overriding the onBackPressed method in all activities and have them create an intent that sends the user to the home screen?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend overriding the back button to make it act like a home button. There is already a home button just for that purpose. Without knowing what your app is I'd say consider leaving the back button as is. If users are getting buried to deep in activities, consider some additional navigation buttons within your app, or perhaps be selective about what activities you are adding to the back stack so that you can have users jump back to more important points in their activity history.